# Forçar arquivo .EML abrir direto no cliente de e-mail

Tags: javascript, html

O Thunderbird permite que uma `'imagem'` do e-mail seja salva em um arquivo, esse arquivo vem no formato `'.EML'`, e em meu sistema, os usuários carregam esse arquivo no sistema junto com o que eles estão fazendo relacionado a determinada empresa.

Mecanismos como Steam, Mega, e sites de torrents pedem para o usuário se eles desejam executar um programa específico ou um programa padrão para o tipo de arquivo.

Acredito que seja algo simples e com HTML mesmo, porém não consegui localizar como fazer isso.

> Como abrir um ext .EML direto no client de e-mail ?

OBS: Se trata de um sistema intranet não há problema em ser invasivo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Isto é apenas um adicional a resposta. Uma ferramenta bacana para isto seria o http://filext.com, se bem que tendo um sistema baseado em Unix ou baseado em Linux é possível fazer isto via linha de comando.

Supondo que você venha a desejar detectar outros tipos de mime-type, em Ubuntu existe o comando `file`, exemplo de uso:

```
file --mime-type arquivo.eml
```

Em PHP (já que foi a solução proposta em sua resposta) pode-se usar o `fileinfo`, algo como:

```
function mimeType($file)
{
    $mimetype = false;

    if (class_exists('finfo')) {//PHP5.4+
        $finfo     = finfo_open(FILEINFO_MIME_TYPE);
        $mimetype  = finfo_file($finfo, $file);
        finfo_close($finfo);
    } else if (function_exists('mime_content_type')) {//php5.3 ou inferiror
        $mimetype = mime_content_type($file);
    }

    return $mimetype;
}
```

O uso seria algo como:

```
$mime = mimeType($file);

if (!$mime) {
    die('Formato desconhecido');
} else {
    $filename = urlencode(basename($file));

    header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=$filename");
    header("Cache-Control: public");
    header("Content-Description: File Transfer");
    header("Content-Type: $mime");
}
```

Note que codifiquei o `filename=` deve conter somente o nome (não tenho certeza se passou o nome completo) seria interessante passar pelo `basename($file)` para obter somente o nome mesmo.

Também é necessário codificar, acaso tenha espaçamento entre os caracteres do nome do arquivo `urlencode(basename($filename))`.

Answer (score 0):

Solução foi apenas com headers mesmo, ele não funcionava apenas porque apontava o programa padrão pelo `'content-type'` estar setado errado, com ***'message/rfc822'*** funcionou corretamente (força o download e sugere o programa, ja é o suficiente):

```
header("Cache-Control: public");
header("Content-Description: File Transfer");
header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=$file");
header("Content-Type: message/rfc822");
header("Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary");
readfile($file);
```